# How to router the page based on certain conditions in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to render the page with react router based on certain condition but the page is not routing.

Comment: can you share your code snippet?

Comment: Can you please share the code as well?

Comment: Can you share the CodePen link of your project?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sanketp45/a7cf792ccc8ff24e50015e003c142a77 please check this out.

Comment: i want to render about page when user clicks the button on home page and page should also render when the manual url like localhost/about entered.

Comment: Try to put your `handleClick()` in `Home` component and try it

Comment: Also, you must wrap your `Home` component with `withRouter` HOC while exporting it.

Comment: Thanks i moved to home component and managed to do it. can you explain how did it work. like i wrapped my home component with routes in app.js and because of it i had access to the location and routes, simply in home i just pushed about to url. is this right>

Comment: You can refer to this, it might help: [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the component you want to use as Link to render another UI component is not any Link, in React Router, you have to use `<Link>` component in this case. If you click on the `<Link>` the *Router* renders the matching `<Route>`, so which implies that you have to have some `<Route>`(s) in your app. Also, if you have multiple `<Route>`s you have to wrap them with `<Switch>` component, if you want to render *exclusively*

> looks through its children`<Route>`s and
> renders the first one that matches the current URL

Here is a quick example closer to yours:

https://codepen.io/shiponcs/pen/OJMEBRg?editors=0011

More on, React-router [Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link), [Switch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch), [Route](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route)